# Upload Numbers file into MySQL table

Tags: mysql, file-upload

I have a .numbers file that looks like this:

```
School Name      |   State Name
-------------------------------------
Lincoln High     |  Colorado
Woods Cross High |  Utah
```

etc.

it has 1000+ rows.

What I want to do import this file `hsdata.numbers` into my MySQL database. How can I do this?

EDIT:
I used this query to upload my csv file:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/Users/username/Documents/hsdata.csv' 
INTO TABLE comments.Schools 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

and I get this error:

`#1045 - Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bro you have to first change this .numbers file to .csv file as .numbers file is develop by apple read this [numbers file](http://file.org/extension/numbers)

for changing it you this [change number to .csv](http://www.benchmarkemail.com/help-FAQ/answer/how-do-i-convert-a-numbers-file-to-an-csv-file)

then you can import into mysql read this [import .csv to sql](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/import-csv-file-mysql-table/)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily convert .numbers to an excel file as follows

Numbers 3.2. Menu > File > Export To > Excel

That will create an Excel copy on your machine.

**METHOD 1:**
1.  Export it into some text format. The easiest will probably be a tab-delimited version, but CSV can work as well.
2.  Use the load data capability. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html
3.  Look half way down the page, as it will gives a good example for tab separated data:
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '\'
4.  Check your data. Sometimes quoting or escaping has problems, and you need to adjust your source, import command-- or it may just be easier to post-process via SQL.

**METHOD 2:**
There's a simple online tool that can do this called databaseimportscriptor.com.
You upload an XLSX file to it, enter a sheet name and cell range, and it will generate a CREATE TABLE statement and a bunch of INSERT statements to import all your data into a MySQL database.

**METHOD 3:**
For a step by step example for importing Excel 2007 into MySQL with correct encoding (UTF-8) search for this comment:

"Posted by Mike Laird on October 13 2010 12:50am"

in the next URL:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html